# Setspace: Make only text body double-spaced and everything else single-spaced

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing, setspace

For the following MWE, I would like to make only the text body double-spaced without affecting chapter titles and references environment.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{someguykey2010,
author="SomeGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2010,
journal="A Journal",
}
@article{someotherguykey2013,
author="SomeOtherGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2013,
journal="A Journal",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter\\Title}

\lipsum[1]

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Remove the option when loading the package and instead add `\doublespacing` when you really want to start double spacing. Use `\singlespacing` to stop double.

Comment: It is good solution for short documents, but for long documents with many chapters/sections/subsections, I would alternate between `\doublespacing` and `\singlespacing` inside each chapter/section/subsection body.

Comment: `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\singlespacing}` or better `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\linespread{1}}`

Comment: Actually, the answer isn't very good. As soon as you use `\doublespacing` the chapter titles are pushed down a bit. This is a common drawback of that package. Maybe @esdd can add a better answer.

Comment: you can give an answer with another package for a better solution. I don't have to use `setspace`.

Comment: As far as i know, setspace does the job best :-)

Comment: @OP It is worth reading the comments provided with the `setspace` package for a sense of why the solution is likely to be less than ideal. @Johannes_B The `singlespace` environment would be more appropriate than `\singlespacing` as the adjustments made are different. I don't know how `\linespread` compares, but `\singlespacing` is intended for use in the preamble and adds a `\baselineskip`. `singlespace` adds and then subtracts a `\baselineskip` and is intended for use within the document for portions of text.

Comment: @cfr, I am sorry for being confused, but are you talking about the answer provided by Johannes_B or something else? Additionally, could you provide a good solution to my question regardless `setspace` is used or not?

Comment: I meant the suggested solution using `\singlespacing`. And, no, I can't provide a good solution. Sorry. As I say, you should read the comments in `setspace` to understand why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not use double-spacing for the headings you could add `\setstretch{1}` to the setting of font element `disposition`:

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\setstretch{1}}
```

As alternative you also could use `\linespread{1}`, but in this case you should additionally append `\selectfont` to the font element somewhere after the `\linespead` command. Otherwise, if a sectioning level would not have a font setting the activation of the new line-spread would be missing.

If you want a sequence of you document without double-spacing use either environment `singlespace` or command `\singlespacing`. But if you would use this before a chapter heading, the vertical space above the chapter head would change. So for the bibliography better use it after the heading, e.g., using `\AfterBibliographyPreamble`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{someguykey2010,
author="SomeGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2010,
journal="A Journal",
}
@article{someotherguykey2013,
author="SomeOtherGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2013,
journal="A Journal",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\setstretch{1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter\\Title}

\lipsum[1]

\nocite{*}

\AfterBibliographyPreamble{\singlespacing}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

You could also use the opposite: Use `doublespacing` environment only for those sequences of your document that should be double-spaced:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{someguykey2010,
author="SomeGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2010,
journal="A Journal",
}
@article{someotherguykey2013,
author="SomeOtherGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2013,
journal="A Journal",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\setstretch{1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter\\Title}

\begin{doublespacing}
\lipsum[1]
\end{doublespacing}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Here the space about chapter heading would be different from the example above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know what you mean by adding `\selectfont` in your statement `"as alternative you also could use \linespread{1}, but in this case you should also add \selectfont"`? Where should I add it?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: See [`fntguide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/fntguide.pdf), section 2.2.